# Properly formatting parameters for POST message in AFNetworking?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, curl, operating-system, afnetworking

So I'm trying to use AFNetworking to essentially pull down the same information that I get with the following cURL request in Terminal:

```
curl --data 'method=my-service.search&document_type=x&keywords=y' http://mywebsite.com/services/json/my-service.search
```

If I type that into Terminal, I get JSON back. Now I want to essentially do the same thing (download the JSON) so I can parse it in Xcode.

I've tried asking this question in different terms here, but I think I'm narrowing in on why I am getting issues — I'm not properly formatting the parameters.

```
NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"document_type", @"keywords", nil];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager POST:urlString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
```

So, how do I perform this task with the right formatting to return proper results? Do I set the urlString to http://mywebsite.com/services/json/my-service.search, should 'method=my-service.search' enter parameters in any form?  How do I define the two parameters that I have listed (e.g.  set document_type to podcast)?

Sorry for the flurry of questions. I'm just frustrating that this web service works so well in Terminal but I can't apply it to Xcode with the knowledge that I currently have.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have created wrong parameters dictionary, the fowolling code

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{"document_type":value, @"keywords":value};

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[manager POST:urlString parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    //SUCCESS BLOCK
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
   //FAILURE BLOCK
}];
```